# Get values from log to csv

Tags: regex, bash

I have problem getting more variables to the column than 4 into my csv file via script

```
cat $1 |
grep "SomeText" |
sed -e "s/^.*var1: \([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\), var2: \([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\), var3: \([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\), var4: \([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\), var5: \([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\), var6: \([0-9]*\)\/\([0-9]*\).*/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9 \10 \11 \12/g" | 
awk "{ printf(\"%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d\\n\", 
    \$1*4294967296+\$2, 
    \$3*4294967296+\$4, 
    \$5*4294967296+\$6, 
    \$7*4294967296+\$8,
    \$9*4294967296+\$10,
    \$11*4294967296+\$12); }" > $1.csv
```

from the log which looks like

```
...
...
19/10/17 11:10:54 SomeText: var1: 0/1538614, var2: 0/1544404, var3: 0/99989, var4: 0/1312988, var5: 0/1312988, var6: 0/1212940
19/10/17 11:10:55 SomeText: var1: 0/2338726, var2: 0/2344516, var3: 0/899999, var4: 0/2113073, var5: 0/2113073, var6: 0/2012977
...
...
```

The first 4 variables are just fine, all var1 values are stored to the first column, var2 values to the second column, etc. The problem starts from fifth var. I cant figure out how to solve it, but I think the problem is in this part of the script

```
.*/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6 \7 \8 \9 \10 \11 \12
```

where the escape character or something like that needs to be used on numbers with two digits (10+) ?

Edit: Expected output

```
  ...     ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
  ...     ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
1538614 1544404 99989  1312988 1312988 1212940
2338726 2344516 899999 2113073 2113073 2012977
  ...     ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
  ...     ...    ...     ...     ...     ...
```

Appreciate any help or advise, thanks.

Comment: If you could mention sample of Input and sample of expected output we will get clear picture of your question.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html : _Back-references are specified with backslash and a single digit._ Also, `cat | grep | sed | awk` is never the path to take. Please, post some sample data with expected output and let us set you on the right path.

Comment: In general, `awk` is more flexible than `sed`. Why not use `awk` on the log file, using regexp functions for parsing, if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valid back references in sed are `\1`, `\2`, ..., `\9`. Your attempt to use `\10 \11 \12` does not work, for example `\10` is interpreted as `\1` followed by a literal `0`.

You need to replace your tool with something more powerful, for example Perl:

```
perl -ne '(@groups = m/: ([0-9]*)\/([0-9]*)/g) && print(join(" ", @groups), "\n")'
```

Given your input example, this will produce lines like these:

> ```
> 0 1538614 0 1544404 0 99989 0 1312988 0 1312988 0 1212940
> 0 2338726 0 2344516 0 899999 0 2113073 0 2113073 0 2012977
> ```

---

Also, using `grep`, `sed`, `awk` in the same pipeline is suspicious,
because all these tools have filtering and stream editing capabilities,
and the most powerful of them can typically do the job of the less powerful ones, with less overhead (fewer running processes).

Some examples:

- `grep foo | sed -e 's/.../.../'` should be replaced with `sed -e '/foo/s/.../.../'`
- `grep foo | awk '{ ... }'` should be replaced with `awk '/foo/ { ... }'`

---

`cat filename | grep pattern` should be replaced with `grep pattern filename`.

Answer (score 0):

One in awk. <s>In the lack of expected output, this may or may not be what you wanted</s>:

```
$ awk '
/SomeText/ {                                     # $3~/^SomeText/ maybe?
    for(i=5;i<=15;i+=2) {                        # fields $5,$7,$9,...,$15
        split($i,a,"/")                          # split by /
        b=b (b==""?"":OFS) a[1]*4294967296+a[2]  # calculate some, buffer to b
    }
    print b                                      # print buffer
    b=""                                         # reset buffer
}' file
```

Output:

```
1538614 1544404 99989 1312988 1312988 1212940
2338726 2344516 899999 2113073 2113073 2012977
```